# helm-find-files (and others): how to prevent C-j from creating buffer when no match

Tags: helm, buffers

When hitting `C-j` in the minibuffer while executing `helm-find-files` and no match is possible, helm creates a new buffer with the name of the completion. E.g. I do `M-x helm-find-files`, type `foo` there is only the default match:

[image: helm with default match]

Now I hi `C-j` and a new buffer gets created, named `foo`. How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you hit `C-j` on no match in the first place. `C-j` is used for previewing the content of a file and there is no needs to preview a non-exist file. But to kill the buffer, simply hit `C-j` again, for example,

```
C-x C-f non-existent-filename C-j C-j
```

the first `C-j` opens a buffer named `non-existent-filename` and the second kills it. I learnt this by reading the documentation. To read the documentation of `helm-find-files`, open a `helm-find-files` session then hit `C-h m` (this is shown in the mode line), or `M-x helm-documentation`.

Comment: I hit it often because of a mistake. E.g. when I mistype for an existing filename: `fop C-j` instead of `foo C-j`; the main problem is that when this new buffer gets created projectile creates a new cache entry for this and I get them when doing a `helm-projectile-find-file`.

Comment: I see though I don't use helm-projectile., thanks for the explanation.

Comment: `helm-projectile` should [no longer](https://github.com/bbatsov/helm-projectile/commit/10531b2634559ea2179f2530423beaac815e9a38) find file with persistent action, only preview it.